# Disabling the Usage button that show associated content used number on the experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, performance

We have a shared datasource item that has been used many times on a component across the site.

When click the component on the experience editor, the browser freezes. Is there anyway to disable the "Usage" button on the toolbar so that the performance can be improved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**\App_Config\Sitecore\Experience Editor\Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Requests.config** configuration file contains declarations of server requests for Sitecore Experience Editor.

The datasource usages account functionality is inside configuration:

```
  <!-- Datasource Usages -->
      <request name="ExperienceEditor.Datasources.GetDatasourceUsagesCount" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.DatasourceUsages.GetDatasourceUsagesCount, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" resolve="true"/>
      <request name="ExperienceEditor.Datasources.GetDatasourceUsagesDialog" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.DatasourceUsages.GetDatasourceUsagesDialog, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" resolve="true"/>
      <request name="ExperienceEditor.Datasources.GetDatasourceUsagesDropdown" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.DatasourceUsages.GetDatasourceUsagesDropdown, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" resolve="true"/>
      <request name="ExperienceEditor.Datasources.GetDatasourceUsagesWithVersions" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.DatasourceUsages.GetDatasourceUsagesWithVersions, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" resolve="true"/>
      <request name="ExperienceEditor.Datasources.GetDatasourceUsagesWithLockedStatus" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.DatasourceUsages.GetDatasourceUsagesWithLockedStatus, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" resolve="true"/>
      <request name="ExperienceEditor.Datasources.GetDatasourceUsagesWithFinalWorkflowStep" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.DatasourceUsages.GetDatasourceUsagesWithFinalWorkflowStep, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon" resolve="true"/>
      <!-- Datasource Usages -->
```

You need to look on **GetDatasourceUsagesCount** .

You can also try too look on frontend side to disabled the call which show you the number of Datasource usages.

You have to edit: `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\ChromeControls.js` and you need to update the function **renderDatasourceUsagesCommand**

Your function will be:

```
renderDatasourceUsagesCommand: function () {
    var container = $sc("");
    return container;
}
```